# Has value function crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my report I have 3 parameters `when, week and year`.
If I select `When=schedule` then the report should run for current week without considering year and week values given in parameter window.
If I select `when=Now` then the report should run for week value and month value that we have given in parameter window.
Please suggest.

I tried like this but not working.

```
if hasvalue({?Week}) and HasValue({?Year}) and {?When} = 'Now'
Then
{?Week} = {Command.WEEK} and {?Year} = {Command.YEAR}
else
({?Week} = DatePart ("ww", Currentdatetime) and {?Year} = DatePart ("yyyy", Currentdatetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

In crystal report ISNULL and INSTR function will use in this condition.

ISNULL:- check the value is null, then return true else false.
INSTR :- check the substring in string, if found then give index else 0 return.

Check detail in links

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/designer/Crystal_Syntax47.html

In your case

```
if isnull({?Week}) and isnull({?Year}) and isnull{?When} 
 Then 
   return false
 else
    //in else again check with if else condition
   if {?When} = 'schedule'
     then
      do something
   else
      do something
```

Comment: If a parameter is optional, you must check that it actually has a value with `hasvalue()`; using `isnull()` will not work and will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

Instead of checking for `null` values for the parameters.. Give a default value for the parameter and check that value for the `false` condition.

Suppose let us take default value as `None`

```
if {?Week}="None" and {?Year}="None" and {?When} = 'Now'
Then
{?Week} = {Command.WEEK} and {?Year} = {Command.YEAR}
else
({?Week} = DatePart ("ww", Currentdatetime) and {?Year} = DatePart ("yyyy", Currentdatetime)
```

`Note: Above code is just an example change it as per your requirement.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use by this way:

```
if {?Week}<>"" then {Command.WEEK}={?Week} else {Command.WEEK}={Command.WEEK}
```

Hope this will help.